# SELECT clause using INTERSECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table DEPTLOC like this:

```
//DEPTLOC
DNAME              CITY
------------------------
RESEARCH          BOSTON
   IT             LONDON
 SCIENCE          BOSTON
SEARCHING         NEWYORK
```

I used the following query:

```
SELECT CITY FROM DNAME WHERE DNAME='RESEARCH'
INTERSECT
SELECT CITY FROM DNAME WHERE DNAME='SCIENCE'
```

So this returns a result like:

```
CITY
---------
BOSTON
```

But how should I change the code so that if any result is found, it will display NO, else it will display YES

Output should be something like this:

```
RESULT
---------
YES
```

or

```
RESULT
---------
NO
```

Comment: You got this -1 because of your writing quality.

Comment: why ? can state what is mean by the writing quality so that i can improve?
-1 doesn't help user anything , think wise . another senior will help junior for the writing quality. but you doesn't help at all. bad

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23471976/revisions . I turned my downvote to an upvote, but you should thank this to @PandaXPress , who fixed your post, and not for yourself.

Comment: Why did you choose `INTERSECT`? Open for other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is counting your results.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM
(
  SELECT CITY FROM DNAME WHERE DNAME='RESEARCH'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT CITY FROM DNAME WHERE DNAME='SCIENCE'
);
```

There are of course other ways to achieve the same result. This one demonstrates how to use your INTERSECT query to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below using `COUNT()` and `DECODE/CASE`

```
SELECT DECODE(COUNT(1),0,'NO','YES') AS RESULT FROM 
(
  SELECT CITY FROM DNAME WHERE DNAME='RESEARCH'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT CITY FROM DNAME WHERE DNAME='SCIENCE'
)
```